# recyclerView android java OnClick item imageView firebase (gif) app fitness

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a list of items that, when clicking on the item, displays an image gif inside the application page from the Firebase database android java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gysou.jpg)

I want to create a list of items that, when clicking on the item, displays an image gif inside the application page from the Firebase database android java

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that? Show us your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.